# Delphi get (and destroy) an instance of a form

Tags: forms, delphi

In an application, that uses a TPanel on a "main form", to display other forms, I need to be able not only to display those forms on the TPanel, but also to close and destroy them using controls (buttons) on the main form.

The goal is following - many buttons, each one displaying a specific form on one panel, on the main form. Then, one button, that kills any possible form, that is currently being displayed (= embedded on the panel). Plus, the same closing/killing action should be called every time, when some of the "opening" buttons are triggered, so if some form is being displayed on the panel, it should be replaced by the new form.

To display a form inside the TPanel, I use something like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not assigned(form4) then
    form4:= TForm4.Create(Panel2);
  form4.Parent:= Panel2;
  form4.Show;
end;
```

Now, to close the window, using another button on the main form, I tried various methods, icluding a `CloseWindow` method, using handles or pointers etc. The most promissing way, was this:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel2.controls[0].Free;
end;
```

It actually closes the form, but since `FreeAndNil` is not used, repeated click on the `Button1`, leads to a nasty series of exceptions, because the form (form4 in this case) has been freed, but the reference to it has not, so the `assigned()` method returns true and then I try to assign a value to something, that no longer exists with `form4.Parent:= Panel2;`. An onClose `Action:= caFree` on the embedded form, does not help either, because the onClose action is not being triggered at all... Placing `FreeAndNil(Form4)` in onDestroy event of the Form4, also leads to a series of exceptions starting with "Invalid pointer operation".

Using

```
procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(Panel2.controls[0]);
end;
```

leads to a following error: `[dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(47): E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter`

So **what is the correct way to get an instance of the embedded form, to be able to use FreeAndNil(...the form...)?** I cannot address it by a name, mainly because I don't know what form is currently being displayed. I need to be able to find an instance of the form based on fact, that it belongs to the `TPanel` on the main form, and then completely destroy it, so that a second click on the Button1, will display it again, and another click on the Button2, will close and destroy it again.

Comment: If you're gonna use "form4" to display the form and if  you're gonna test if the reference is "assigned" before displaying it, then you have to nil "form4" when you destroy the form. That means in your current design you have to address the embedded form by name.

Comment: The test is there only to avoid a problem with creating a form, that already exists (due to auto create or whatever).... I updated the question to better clarify my intentions

Comment: Anyway, if you want the DCC error get resolved: you don't need to nil an element in the controls array, it will get deleted anyway. If you're asking something else and want the question to make sense, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to the solution is `Vcl.Forms.TFormClass`. From the documentation:

> TFormClass is the metaclass for TForm. Its value is the class
>   reference for TForm or for one of its descendants.

And use it as follows:

First, ditch the `FormN` global variables from all units that define forms that you will be showing in the panel of the main form. You will not need them and deleting them will prevent you from doing mistakes.

Secondly, in the main form, add a private declaration, `CurrentForm: TForm` and a private `procedure ShowForm`

```
...
private
  CurrentForm: TForm;
  procedure ShowForm(aFormClass: TFormClass);
...
```

Because of the `aFormClass: TFormClass` argument, you can pass in any form type.

Write event handlers for the buttons that should create and show the forms in the panel, similar to this:

```
procedure TForm25.ShowFormAClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowForm(TForm26);
end;
```

And write the `ShowForm()` method:

```
procedure TForm25.ShowForm(aFormClass: TFormClass);
begin
  CurrentForm.Free;
  CurrentForm := aFormClass.Create(self);
  CurrentForm.Parent := Panel1;
  CurrentForm.Show;
end;
```

Finally also write the event handler for the button that should hide whatever form is currently displayed:

```
procedure TForm25.ShowNothingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(CurrentForm);
end;
```

Comment: This is the key I have been missing - the metaclass. This works perfectly. Many thanks

Comment: @j.k - What happened to *"one button, that kills every possible form, that is currently being displayed"*? How does this code address that?

Comment: @Sertac Maybe I can answer. A button called `ShowNothing` and its `ShowNothingClick` event handler.

Comment: I think you think there's only one form active at a time. But I don't know why do you think that.

Comment: @Sertac According to the problem presentation, 2nd paragraph,  there can be only one form at a time in the panel. Maybe you think too much about the phrase *that kiills **every** possible*. That should be read *...any...*

Comment: @j.k So what will some of the opening buttons do while some other will close the open form? *"... closing/killing action should be called every time, when some of the "opening" buttons are triggered..."*

Comment: each button, that spawns a new form, will first do the same thing, as the closing button does

Comment: I did read the whole question several times. j.k - you're lucky @Tom understood your problem. The whole question is a mess. It could be a two liner that states the problem clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying to be as clear as possible. A "two liner" question here on SO, usually ends up worse than this... I still believe, that the very question, that is now highlited (bold), is pretty clear. The rest is only to better understand the situation and describe what I tried to do

Comment: Anyway, you can let go of any tracking. You've asked the wrong question. You don't have to use FreeAndNil. As my third comment to the question suggests, and as commented under another answer, you can simply use Panel2.controls[0].Free. You don't have to nil anything and you don't have to test for Assigned.

Comment: In the end, I actually have to test it. The reasons are really beyond the scope of this question (they would make it even a bigger mess). The Tom's solution works well

Answer (score 1):

## What you're doing wrong

You're completely misunderstanding Delphi's default global form variables. E.g. in this case `Form4: TForm4;`. (And yet again, I lament the fact that Delphi clings to this horrendous design shortcut.)

Just because Delphi happens to generate this for you doesn't give it any special meaning. You ***cannot*** assume it in any way binds to a specific *instance* of `TForm4`. And you most certainly ***shouldn't*** assume its `Assigned` status gives any indication how many instances of the form exist. *Indeed, as you've noticed, even when `Assigned(Form4) = True` it's possible the instance that `Form4` **was** referring to has already been destroyed.*

To gain a better understanding, experiment with the following:

```
{Add these to your main form}
FForm4a: TForm4;
FForm4b: TForm4;
FHelloWorld: TForm4;

{Try the following in a button click event
 You should see 3 instances of TForm4.}
FForm4a := TForm4(Self);
FForm4b := TForm4(Self);
FHelloWorld := TForm4(Self); {You might not have realised, but the
                              identifier can be completely different
                              to the class name.}
FForm4a.Show();
FForm4b.Show();
FHelloWorld.Show();

{In another try}
FreeAndNil(FHelloWorld);
if not Assigned(FHelloWorld) then
  ShowMessage('Code explicitly ensured the reference to the form was cleared.');
FForm4b.Free;
if Assigned(FForm4b) then
  ShowMessage('If you do not clear the reference, the form variable *remains* assigned.');

{Finally close all TForm4 instances through the UI
(if your form settings allow it), and call the following.}
if Assigned(FForm4a) then
  ShowMessage('Form4a is assigned.');
if Assigned(FForm4b) then
  ShowMessage('Form4b is assigned.');
if Assigned(FHelloWorld) then
  ShowMessage('HelloWorld is assigned.');
```

---

## So how can you solve your problem?

For a start if you want to know about forms that are on `Panel2`, check `Panel2`! *Don't waste time checking global variables that have **nothing** to do with what's on `Panel2`*.

```
function TMainForm.DoesForm4Exist(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  for I := 0 to Panel2.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    if (Panel2.Controls[I] is TForm4) then Exit;
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

You now have a reliable way to check if `Panel2` ***currently has*** a `TForm4` instance. And this should set you on the right path.

---

## Improving the solution

You can make the above code generic so you can reuse it for your other forms. At the same time, you can return a reference to the form, so you interact with it programatically. E.g. to destroy it:

```
function TMainForm.FindForm(AFormClass: TFormClass): TForm;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for I := 0 to Panel2.ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    if (Panel2.Controls[I] is AFormClass) then
    begin
      Result := TForm(Panel2.Controls[I])
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

{Example using the code to find and destroy a TForm4 instance}
LForm := FindForm(TForm4);
if Assigned(LForm) then LForm.Free;
```

You can similarly make the form creation generic as per [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461220/224704).

Comment: Although I cannot use the proposed method, because it still works with an asumption, that I know which form TForm4 (TForm5, TForm100 ...) is being used, It nicely clarifies the problematics of the global form variables. Thank you

Comment: @j.kaspar Well... your question created the impression you wanted only one instance of each form on your `Panel2`. If that's not the case. then your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, I do want only one instance of each form, but the problem is, that the program doesn´t know which form is being used. So I cannot do `LForm := FindForm(TForm4);` because it can be TForm4, it can be TForm100 or whatever... I just don't know which form is on the panel now. And that is what I believed I need to find out

Comment: Well in that case if it's only ever 0 or 1 control (or form) on the panel, then `if (Panel2.CountrolCount = 1) then Panel2.Controls[0].Free;`

Answer (score -1):

Your main problem is, you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Mainly, you don't need to keep track of the form that is potentially being displayed in the panel and hence you don't have to use `FreeAndNil` at all.

That is because you can ask the panel anytime what it has got, and since you know what form you are attempting to display when you click a button, you can specifically ask the panel if it has got that kind of specific form.

```
procedure DisplayFormInPanel(Panel: TPanel; FormClass: TFormClass);
begin
  if (Panel.ControlCount > 0) and not (Panel.Controls[0] is FormClass) then
    Panel.Controls[0].Free;

  if Panel.ControlCount = 0 then
  begin
    with FormClass.Create(Panel) do begin
      Parent := Panel;
      Show;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The above procedure gets rid of any possible form that is not of the kind you want to display. If there's already a form that is of the kind that is going to be displayed, then nothing happens - the form stays in the panel.

Call it like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DisplayFormInPanel(Panel2, TForm4);
end;
```

And your button click handler that closes any form could be as simple as

```
  if Panel.ControlCount > 0 then
    Panel.Controls[0].Free;
```

Regarding the DCC error, there is no point in pursuing that because the reference in the controls array is not the same as the "form4" reference. Even if you could nil that reference, it wouldn't effect "form4" and hence would not help with testing for `Assigned`. And the reference in the controls array is going to be removed from the controls array as soon as the form is freed anyway.